# Matching brace in visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio

In visual studio, matching braces are automatically highlighted when placing the cursor *outside* of the brace. Is there a way to have the same behaviour with the cursor inside the brackets?

I would find it useful because when you click at the opening of a loop for instance, you are more naturally inside than outside of the brackets

```
for(var i=0; i<3; i++)
{ //you click this side more easily than on the other one
    //
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that's possible, too. But for code like your example I found structure guide lines extremly helpful. This adds dotted lines between the braces, so there's less need to highlight them:

[image: Structure guide lines]

You can enable it in VS 2017 via **Options>Text Editor>General>Show structure guide lines** and for older versions of Visual Studio I used the Extension [Indent Guides](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SteveDowerMSFT.IndentGuides).

Hope it can help your need, too.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that this is possible.

However, you can try to use `Ctrl+]` to jump to the closing bracket.

You can read more about it [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/da5kh0wa.aspx#Anchor_30).

Comment: thanks for the hint. For information, `]` corresponds to `^` on Azerty keyboards

Answer (score 0):

If you click on the closing brace it highlights via inside click too

Anyway you can find useful tools for programming with this extension:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioProductTeam.ProductivityPowerTools2015